# SharePoint Search KQL XRANK count of matches

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I have wrote a customed KQL query for our SharePoint search.
I'm using SharePoint 2013.
By default, SharePoint gives some ranking to results which contains the exact term, to results which contains some of the term's words and to results that contains the term several times.

My customed query gives some ranking according to some managed properties. It gives the highest ranking to results which contains part of the term in the Title, and lower ranking to results which contians part of the term in some other managed properties.

The problem is that now, the original ranking of SharePoint OOTB gets the lowest priority. I need the priority of the ranking will be as the following:

1) Title

2) exact match, number of occurrences etc.

3) my other ranked managed properties.

-

My current query seems like that:

`(((MyTerm Path:http://domainname/Lists/ListName/  (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)) XRANK(cb=100) ManagedProperty1:MyTerm) XRANK(cb=200) ManagedProperty2:MyTerm) XRANK(cb=300) title:MyTerm`

-

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any help??? Where are all the experts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

I should have written "nb" (meaning neutral boost) rather than "cb" (meaning constant boost).

With neutral boost, the ranking which I specifies is integrated with the SharePoint OOTB ranking rules (exact match, number of occurrences, popularity etc).